# How to send push notification to a offline user ejabberd

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-module

Hi I am new with Ejabberd and I don't know how to send push notification to an offline user I check in previous posts related to this topic and I found a solution in which we have to create a separate module which triggers whenever message store in offline message and it call a rest API which can send notification but it's a very lengthy Process and need another server to complete the task which is not good.
I found mod_push module but as I understand it's not for offline user please correct me if I am wrong and please guide for the best solution

Comment: mod_push is for offline users, but you need a separate component (like the one used by conversations client) to send push notifications.

Comment: Hi @MickaëlRémond I Checked the [conversations](https://github.com/siacs/Conversations) but I didn't get the separate component for push notification what I get `PushManagementService` but didn't get any help from here

Comment: Ah, maybe they did not publish their component for their open source client?

Comment: Do you know any place from which I can read more about it and implement it?

Comment: I think the reference is https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0357.html